# Restrict shipping method based on product attribute

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, after-plugin

I'm trying to restrict a shipping method in `afterCollectRates` based on a custom product attribute (which I'm injecting with the help of `catalog_attributes.xml`

```
public function afterCollectRates(Tablerate $tablerate, $result)
{
    $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getMyAttribute()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This hides the shipping method if there's a product **with** the attribute in cart. However, I need the exact opposite. I need to hide the shipping method if **no** product in cart does have the attribute.

Obviously the cart can have products **with** and **without** the attribute, so I can not simply do `!$item->getProduct()->getBulkgood()` since the function only accepts `return: false;`

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will only show the shipping method when item contains your attribute otherwise it will return false.

```
public function afterCollectRates(Tablerate $tablerate, $result)
{
    $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getMyAttribute()) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I also found I can hook into aroundCollectCarrierRates method. There I could combine several shipping restrictions. I think this is even better, or do you think the after plugin is the better way to go? Thanks